# MobFox gives me back always "No inventory for ad request"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ads

I've just implemented MobFox but for the last 4 days my only response back is "No inventory for ad request". Likely it is because there is No inventory for ad request but it is very suspicious. AdMob gives me answer almost always. I'm in Czech Republic and it is posible that users in other countries will get the ads but I have no way to test it so far. 
I'm using cocos2d to build an iPad app.
Could you help me out with some of these?

1. Is there a way force MobFox to serve test ads (I've searched for it but failed)
2. Is it possible that I'm doing something wrong? E.g. some setup in the account? My status for the site has turned green just after I've sent first requests. I even tried to BackFill to InMobi (pending status at this moment).

Appreciate your help --Josef

Comment: I've just created a House Ad and it shows up so I guess I have to believe that my users in other countries will see the real ads.

Comment: I suggest taking question #2 to MobFox support instead. They will be able to tell you if there's anything wrong with your account, their network, or them serving ads in the Czech Republic. Number #1 you should also be able to find an answer by contacting MobFox support. All ad providers have some way to test ads, mostly to avoid creating false impressions while you're developing your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. to test your ads: use a new (unactivated) publisher id
2. everything was fine, at this time there were no ads in CZ.